# Pixel Art - Very beginner help guides (Intermediate-Expert computer user, rookie artist)

Tags: pixel-art

Hi everyone my first time here but I'm hoping to turn a lot of my attention toward working on graphic design. I already have a fair bit of experience making 3d scenes (Blender, Maya, Max, etc), and I make games in Unity (not very good ones yet, but they are getting better :D)

My first love (you never forget your first love!) is 2D pixel games and art. (and the 8-bit-ish sound tracks!) I want to bring this stuff back to life in my own projects but every time I try I fail on my art, and end up cheating and using someone elses.

For this specific start of my learning, I already have made the core of a game. Its an adventure game set in 3D and I have basic assets already.

BUT: For the Inventory Menu GUI. I want to have a 120x120 pixel art version of every item you can collect in the game.

(Items such ranging from keys/door handle -> To bags of strange green vegetables etc LOL).

Do you have any tips on how to draw that stuff (Ie. Do you get a picture of some real keys and then 'trace' it , or do you draw by hand in GIMP with pencil 1 pixel at a time without any guide?)

Any first tips you can offer, or links to concise tutorials would be great (hopefully ones without someone talking wayyyy to much over it all the time as cannot watch them for long lol).
I really also would like to know how other artists are adding a 'lighting effect' on their 2D art. I've seen video of them with like ovals of yellow, but it doesnt work when I try

So yeah I have GIMP, Inkscape and I'm thinking about buying Aseprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indirectly pointed in your question, Pixel Art is something with too many years. During all this time many applications have appeared that do almost everything, a good start to make minimal adjustments if necessary.

As an example [Pixelator](http://pixelatorapp.com/).

> Software to convert images into pixel art sprites and cover arts. With Pixelator you can use any source picture to easily generate Pixelated graphics for games or posters.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much this looks great! I will check it now :D Damn! I was behind the times, I was dreaming something like this would exist (almost considering how I could try to make one lol!) I can happily churn out some stuff now hopefully!) Thats made my Christmas haha

Comment: The software is wonderful. The possiblities are limitless .... many thanks for pointing it out